# onDraw not working properly. It only shows for one second and then dissapears

Tags: android, draw, surfaceview

I am having problem with drawing. It only shows the elements it should draw for a second and then it is empty again. I am drawing in android surface view. Here is the code:

```
private void drawSurface(Canvas canvas) {
   canvas.drawColor(Color.YELLOW);
   for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i) {

    System.out.println(i);
    point2 = points.get(i);
    canvas.drawCircle(point2.x, point2.y, RADIUS, paint);
    canvas.drawText(characters.get(i), point2.x, point2.y, tpaint);

}}
```

Here is where I call this method:

```
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    addPoints();
    Canvas canvas = null;
    canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
    if (null != canvas) {
        System.out.println("Created");
        drawSurface(canvas);
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }


}
```

Comment: I can see, there might be an `Index out of bound` exception on the last iteration. Try doing `i++` instead of `++i`.

Comment: @PrerakSola: post-vs-pre-increment doesn't matter on an integer in a for loop.

Comment: Looking at the code above, you're drawing once, when the Surface is first created. I'm guessing you've got other code that draws on the Surface or the View later on that erases or covers what you drew initially.

Comment: No, I am only using this for drawing.